# IDE, Text Editor, Program that can save "snapshots" of your code? (Auto-save backups of code)

Tags: ide, backup, versioning

I've been looking for an IDE or Text Editor that can save "snapshots" of my code. I have been coding in a lot of new languages lately using a lot of trial and error. I often find myself wanting to revert a file or multiple files because of a coding/design decisions made in the last couple of hours or even days. It would be nice if I could take a snapshot of my code periodically and reverting to a past snapshot rather than manually making copies of my files on intervals.

I'd imagine that there has to be atleast an editor that shows version-history of a file. ( I realize I could use git or svn or any other versioning solution, but I'd like a more automated process.)

(if not an IDE, does anyone know how to configure Windows-ShadowCopy, OSX-TimeMachine, to make backups of my development folder on 45min intervals... or even a third-party program.)

Comment: I think I'd actually prefer a program rather than being stuck with an IDE, but the ability to quickly view version history could potentially persuade me to use a new IDE/Text-Editor.

Comment: Why can't you just automate check-ins to source control? That would be a lot easier and more flexible than an IDE-specific feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse takes a local history on a per file basis... but personally I would strongly suggest using source control for this. If you use something like git or Mercurial, your commits are all local anyway - and it means you'll have a consistent snapshot at moments where you believe you've reached a useful point.

With a bit of experience it only takes a few seconds to commit your current work, and I think it's likely to prove more useful over time than automatically snapshotting either every save or at random intervals.

(It's hard to know whether Eclipse will actually be useful to you, as you haven't specified which language you'll be programming in. Admittedly there are plugins for a fair number of languages in Eclipse...)